# How to make text or label selectable?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Let's say I have text component:

```
Text {      
      text: "Hello"
      wrapMode: Text.WordWrap    
}
```

How to make it selectable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is a bug reported: [QTBUG-14077](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-14077), and the workaround is to use `TextEdit` in read-only mode:

```
TextEdit {
    text: "Hello"
    readOnly: true
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    selectByMouse: true
}
```